# C# How to import textbox.text as object(in class) variable? Windows Forms app

Tags: c#

I need to import the text that is inside "Parallel_quantity" textbox into the class object, but i get this error: CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property

Below is my code:

```
  class production_ordered
    {
        string production_time_obj;
        int parallel_ordered;
        int linear_ordered;
        string type;


       
        public void Ordered_prd()
        {
            production_ordered MyObj1 = new production_ordered();
            bool par;
            int a;
            par = int.TryParse(Parallel_quantity.Text, out a);
            MyObj1.parallel_ordered = a;
        }

    }
```

How to deal with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who is calling Ordered_prd? Inside the class production_ordered there is no knowledge of what _Parellel_quantity_ is and even if it has a Text property. You should pass the string from the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel_quantity is a property of the Form it is placed on (more specifically - the class created for the Form). It does not exist in the context of the `production_ordered` class.

To deal with it, you have several options. The simplest suggestion would be to move the `Ordered_prd` method outside of the `production_ordered` class, inside of your Form class (e.g. Form1).
You would also need to change

```
int parallel_ordered;
```

into

```
public int parallel_ordered;
```

in order to make it accessible in the method.

Resulting code would be something like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Ordered_prd()
    {
        production_ordered MyObj1 = new production_ordered();
        bool par;
        int a;
        par = int.TryParse(Parallel_quantity.Text, out a);
        MyObj1.parallel_ordered = a;
    }
}

class production_ordered
{
    string production_time_obj;
    int linear_ordered;
    string type;

    public int parallel_ordered;
}
```